# Position of the objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

I want to get all the top positions of objects, but then the browser throws an error:

```
sections[i].position is not a function
```

```js
$(window).scroll(function (event) {
        var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
        var sections = $("[id*='sec-']");
        
        for (i=0; i < sections.length; i++) {
            sections[i] = sections[i].position();
            console.log(sections[i]);
        }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="sec-1" class="section"></section>
<section id="sec-2" class="section"></section>
<section id="sec-3" class="section"></section>
<section id="sec-4" class="section"></section>
```

Comment: Isn't it obvious that `sections[i].position()` does not exist?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

.position() is not a javascript function.
What you mean is the jQuery function $.position().

Therefore your code:

```
sections[i].position();
```

is wrong and must be like the following:

```
$(sections[i]).position();
```

Here's a updated version of your JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2xs2Ljz9/

Hope this helps you. Have a nice day.